# Multibyte characters in Password field

Tags: html

Is it possible to make a user type multibyte characters, such as Japanese Language in the password field in an HTML Page?If so, how? If not, then why can't we type multi-byte characters but copy-paste them in the password field?

Comment: Any sample or code, please? Why *we can't*? If you don't restrict passwords with your logic and store them encrypted, where is the problem?

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë What I meant is, when we try to give input using Japanese language, we can enter into the text box using the on-screen keyboard provided by Windows, but when we type into the password field, it gets entered as english. But copy-pasting a Japanese text into the password field is possible. I wanted to know how to give Japanese language text as password by typing into the password field.

Comment: So you want a possibility to type in *using an on-screen keyboard*? If so, I think you need to update your question because as for me, there's no problem to install a Japanese keyboard layout and enter a password. I don't speak Japanese but I do speak Ukrainian and Russian which use Cyrillic script. So, for instance, I can type *ПривітСвіте* (which is *HelloWorld* in Ukrainian) into any password field, if (I repeat this!) the developer didn't restrict the password field to English letters, numbers and special chars only.

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë I did try installing the Japanese keyboard layout .For text field, it works whereas for the password field, it gets entered as english characters only.

Comment: Well... this is really odd. I hope there are some Japanese speakers here to help you.

Comment: Could you please tell me any changes in the settings that you made so as to type in the Cyrillic script?

Comment: Well, I installed the corresponding keyboard layouts. Then I set the Windows locale to Russian (this is not required! but you might try).

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë Does the keyboard work for all the browsers? Which browser are you using?

Comment: At least, it should work for every browser. I tested with IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë Are you using ime-mode attribute for the text fields and password fields in the html page?

Comment: Never ever. And even didn't know about it, just googled :)

Comment: I suppose this limitation is exerted by browsers and not [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#password-state-%28type=password%29).